# Code shortening membership check in set

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a set that contains all the items I want to print out. However, the output should be different based on whatever else is in the set. Here is an example:

```
for i in set(range(10))-{a*b for a in range(2,5)for b in range(2,4)}:
print i if i-1 not in set(range(10))-{a*b for a in range(2,5)for b in range(2,4)}and i+1 not in set(range(10))-{a*b for a in range(2,5)for b in range(2,4)}else `i`+"!"

#For readability purposes, here is the unshortened code

originalNumbers = set(range(10))
numbersToRemove = set([a*b for a in range(2,5) for b in range(2,4)])
finalList = originalNumbers - numbersToRemove

for number in finalList:
    if number - 1 in finalList or number + 1 in finalList:
        print str(number) + "!"
    else:
        print number
```

The output is:

```
0!
1!
2!
3!
5
7
```

which is correct. Is there a shorter way I can do this without having to copy the original set again and still maintain a code that can be written in one line/statement?

**Note:**
The set doesn't have to be the one I specified, I just used that as an example.

Comment: There is so much wrong with this. First of all, what the heck are you even trying to do, am I supposed to unwind that two lines in my head? Second, why on earth do you want a oneliner? Your code is *completely* unreadable and any colleague would smack you.

Comment: @timgeb the objective of the program is to be one line long, so the code has to be written like this.

Comment: @BobMarshall I agree with `timgeb`. Whoever told you to make that one line is not a nice person.

Comment: @Kris It's a question about solving a sort of code golf style program. I'm just wondering if anyone knows how to do this sort of thing in python.

Comment: @BobMarshall so, you're actually trying to write this in one line? Why though?

Comment: @Kris The question I'm trying to solve has to do with creating a one line prime sieve, except the number being printed changes depending on the other numbers in the prime list. The objective is to do this efficiently and in one line with a character limit.

Answer (score 1):

You could save a single copy of the `set` off in a named variable outside the loop, then use that saved `set` later.

Since your goal appears to be a one-liner though, you have to abuse list comprehensions/generator expressions to achieve this. The "nice" way to do this is to have the first loop be a loop over a single element `tuple` containing the value you want precomputed, allowing you to store it and use it without adding lines. For your particular example, it could be done as:

```
print '\n'.join(str(i) if i-1 not in s and i+1 not in s else str(i)+'!' for s in (set(range(10)) - {a*b for a in range(2,5) for b in range(2,4)},) for i in s)
```

Ugly, but then, you're writing one-liners and playing code golf, so ugly is unavoidable. It could be shortened further (for example, `i-1 not in s and i+1 not in s` could be alternatively expressed by reversing the `if` and `else` cases and testing `{i-1, i+1} & s`), but this version is close enough to your example code to be recognizable.